# How do I create tests for a library that I am creating in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Right now I am trying to create and debug an sfml game engine, but it has gotten to the point where I need a full folder setup to create a project. I have the in-development library in another folder from where I am programming my tests. My folder hierarchy looks like:

```
SFMLEngine
|
|- src
   |- .h files
   |- .cpp files
|- bin
   |- .o files
|- tests
   |- onefiletest.cpp
   |- testdir
      |- Makefile
      |- src
         |- main.cpp
         |- engine (symlink to src/ of main directory)
      |- resources
         |- resources.h (generated by script)
         |- findresources.py (goes through resources/ dir and generates resources.h to assign a variable to the resource path)
```

Example main.cpp for testdir:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "engine/input.h"
#include "../resources/resources.h"

int main() {
  // Do stuff
}
```

My problem is that when I try and compile the project, g++ does not follow the symlink for the #include "engine/input.h"

Is there a way to have g++ follow the symlink, or am I creating these tests in a sloppy way?

Comment: You should probably investigate the `-I` flag for gcc.

Comment: What is g++'s output? Do you build the .cpp files in src separately? My version of g++ can follow symbolic links to include header files.

Comment: Use your compiler's built in support for additional include paths, rather than symlinks, as suggested by Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-I` flag ended up doing what I want. I edited my makefile and everything compiles great.